SwiftUI Fix Value Multi updates
In the next code, I have two views "SelectSymbolView" which contains "SymbolCategorySection", the issue is in "SymbolCategorySection" which updates "selectedSymbol" four times when the user taps on a symbol to select it even when I ensure to not update "selectedSymbol" until it's necessary.
The SelectSymbolView:
struct SelectSymbolView: View {
    
    // MARK: - Properties
    @Binding var selectedSymbol: String
    @State private var selectedCategory: SymbolCategory = .cloths
    @State private var dismissView = false
    let categories = SymbolCategory.allCases
    let symbolGridColumns = [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 48, maximum: 48), spacing: 11, alignment: .center)]
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
    
    // MARK: - Body
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ScrollViewReader { scrollProxy in
                ScrollView {
                    LazyVStack(spacing: 18) {
                        ForEach(categories, id: \.self) { category in
                            SymbolCategorySection(selectedSymbol: $selectedSymbol, category: category)
                                .id(category.title)
                        }
                        .padding(.horizontal, 16)
                    }
                }
                .offset(y: 16)
                .overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
                    CategoryTapBar(selectedCategory: $selectedCategory, categories: categories)
                        .offset(y: -22)
                }
                .onChange(of: selectedCategory, initial: false) { _, _ in
                    withAnimation(.smooth(duration: 0.3)) {
                        scrollProxy.scrollTo(selectedCategory.title, anchor: .top)
                    }
                }
                .onChange(of: selectedSymbol, initial: false, { _, _ in
                    dismissView = true
                })
                .task(id: selectedSymbol, priority: .userInitiated) {
                    guard dismissView else { return }
                    try? await Task.sleep(seconds: 0.7)
                    dismiss()
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Select Symbol")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .background(Color(.systemGroupedBackground))
            .interactiveDismissDisabled(true)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarLeading) {
                    CancelButton(isToolbarItem: true) { dismiss() }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
}

The SymbolCategorySection view
extension SelectSymbolView {
    
    struct SymbolCategorySection: View { 
        
        // MARK: - Properties
        @Binding var selectedSymbol: String
        let category: SymbolCategory
        let symbolGridColumns = [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 48, maximum: 48), spacing: 11, alignment: .center)]
        
        // MARK: - Body
        var body: some View {
            LazyVStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
                // Section Title
                HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 12) {
                    Image(systemName: category.symbolName)
                        .font(.title3)
                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                        .frame(width: 24, height: 24)
                    Text(category.title)
                        .font(.title2)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                }
                .foregroundStyle(Color(.secondaryLabel))
                .padding(.horizontal, 8)
                // Section Symbols
                LazyVGrid(columns: symbolGridColumns, alignment: .center, spacing: 11) {
                    ForEach(category.symbols, id: \.self) { symbolData in
                        TaskSymbol(systemName: symbolData.systemName,
                                   style: .selection,
                                   color: symbolColor(for: symbolData))
                        .overlay(alignment: .bottomTrailing, content: {
                            if symbolData.isPlus {
                                AppPlus(type: .symbol)
                            }
                        })
                        .onTapGesture {
                            select(symbolData.systemName)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .padding(.vertical, 9)
                .background(SettingItemBackground())
            }
            .sensoryFeedback(.selection, trigger: selectedSymbol)
            .onChange(of: selectedSymbol, initial: false) { oldValue, newValue in
                print(" selected Symbol changed") <<< Use it to indicate update times
            }
        }
        
        // MARK: - Actions
        private func select(_ symbol: String) {
            if selectedSymbol != symbol {
                withAnimation(.smooth(duration: 0.3)) {
                    selectedSymbol = symbol
                }
            }
        }
        
        private func symbolColor(for symbolData: SymbolData) -> Color {
            if selectedSymbol == symbolData.systemName {
                return Color(.systemBlue)
            }
            if symbolData.isPlus {
                return Color(.secondaryLabel)
            }
            return Color(.charcoalGray)
        }
        
    }
}


You are passing the same selectedSymbol instance to all SymbolCategorySection views you create. You need to have separate instances for each view.
